# On the asymptotic behaviour of the kernel of a Toeplitz operator

Tags: schrodinger-operators, large-deviations, toeplitz-operators

Consider the following Berezin Topelitz operator on the 2-sphere:

$$Q_N(f)=\frac{N+1}{4\pi}\int_{\mathbb{S}^2}d\Omega \,  f(\Omega)|\Omega\rangle\langle\Omega|_N,$$

where $f\in C^\infty(\mathbb{S}^2)$, $d\Omega$ is the standard measure on the sphere, and  with the Bra-ket notation $\lvert\Omega\rangle\langle\Omega\lvert_N$, I mean the projection onto the one-dimensional subspace spanned by coherent spin state vector $\lvert\Omega\rangle_N$, given by the $N$-fold tensor product of $\lvert\Omega\rangle_1$ with itself, where $\lvert\Omega\rangle_1=\cos\frac{\theta_\Omega}{2} \lvert\uparrow\rangle+e^{i\phi_\Omega}\sin\frac{\theta_\Omega}{2}|\downarrow\rangle$ denotes the Bloch vector parameterized by the point $\Omega=(\theta_\Omega, \phi_\Omega)$, with polar angle $\theta_\Omega\in (0,\pi)$ and azimuth $\phi_\Omega\in (-\pi,\pi)$. Here, $\lvert\uparrow\rangle$ and $\lvert\downarrow\rangle$ are eigenvectors of the spin Pauli matrix $\sigma_3$ in $\mathbb{C}^2$, i.e. $\sigma_3\lvert\uparrow\rangle=\lvert\uparrow\rangle$ and $\sigma_3\lvert\downarrow\rangle=-\lvert\downarrow\rangle$.

In particular, the berezin operator maps the constant one function to the unit operator (resolution of identity) and $Q_N(f)$ can be seen as bounded operator on $\mathbb{C}^{N+1}$. Now, one can multiply $Q_N(f)$ by a factor $N$ and consider the following expression for the kernel corresponding to the semi-group $e^{-tNQ_N(f)}(\Omega_1,\Omega_2)$ ($t>0$), namely

$$\frac{1}{N}\log \left[ e^{-tNQ_N(f)}(\Omega_1,\Omega_2) \right].$$

My question: does anyone know if this converges poinwise, and if so, to what?

Possible ideas: suitable application of Varadhan's lemma, and perhaps the relation with Schrödinger operators, see e.g. 'Feynman path integral and Toeplitz quantization' (Helvetica Physica Acta, 1999) by L. Charles.

I thank you in advance.